# Insert document in Cosmos DB using PowerShell (SQL API)

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I'm getting an error when I am trying to insert data in Cosmos DB collection having Partition Key.

Without Partition key, it's working fine

```
$resourceGroupName = "myrg"
$cosmosDbAccountName = "mydb"
$databaseName = "test"

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDbAccountName -        
Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName    

New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'events' -OfferThroughput 1000 -PartitionKey 'RuleType' -DefaultTimeToLive 604800

$document = @"
{
        "id": "$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())",
        "createTime": "2018-05-21T22:59:59.999Z",
        "RuleType": "FTOD"
    }

"@
New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 'events' - 
DocumentBody $document  -PartitionKey 'RuleType'
```

> "RuleType": This is my Partition Key

[image]

Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CosmosDB\2.1.4.536\lib\utils.ps1:554 char:30
+ ... estResult = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing @invokeWebRequestParam ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Anyone know about this??

Comment: I would really suggest you to add your error message as text, not as an image. It makes it easier to read, copy, evaluate, search for, et cetera

Comment: Why are you instantiating `$document` as String? You could just use `ConvertTo-Json`. It helps you to ensure, your json is valid.

Comment: good suggestion! not any specific reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue on my side.

[image]

Based on parameter list which `Get-Help New-CosmosDbDocument` command shows:

[image]

You need to add `partitionkey` and you could insert document successfully.

```
$resourceGroupName = "***"
$cosmosDbAccountName = "***"
$databaseName = "db"

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDbAccountName -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName    

$document = @"
{
        "id": "6fa9b3d5-ce1a-4b38-9068-9d17de5b1c69",
        "createTime": "2018-05-21T22:59:59.999Z",
        "RuleType": "FTOD"           
    }

"@
$partitionkey = "FTOD"
New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 'part' -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey $partitionkey
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Are you able to insert data?? I already tried this (I updated my question with the complete command) but still getting 400 error.

Comment: Why you used $partitionkey = "A" If partitionKey attribute name is RuleType??

Comment: Yes,I inserted data successfully.In you situation,please use $partitionkey = "FTOD"